# Control formula field display based on User

Tags: formula-field, static-resources, images, record-access-level, image-formula

I have a requirement to display an Alert image that I have uploaded as a static resource to the User who is viewing the record only if the User is owner of the record.

Can someone please guide me here?

Comment: Do you mean- alert image on record standard view page in a formula or as a Pop Up?

Comment: Yes in a formula

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it to be a formula field, this is how you should proceed :

1. Upload the image in static resource. Lets consider name is **OwnershipImage**
2. Create a formula field on Object with below formula :

   **IF( $User.Id == OwnerId ,IMAGE("/resource/OwnershipImage", "I am owner",40,600),''))**
3. 40,600 is the height and the width respectively you are looking to set for this image.
4. You can also set the default image if you want in the **Value if No** part of the **IF** formula we used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19282/discussion-between-amit-bangad-and-sfdc-geek).